# Composer Require 'package' throws OpenSSL error

Tags: php, composer-php, ssl-certificate, packagist

This problem seems to be common, and i've been through a lot of SO posts related to it and nothing works, and i'm going crazy. Whats weird is that it was working perfectly few weeks ago, and i didnt install anything new since months...

***Setup :***

- PHP 7.1.9
- WAMPSERVER 3.1.0
- APACHE 2.4.27
- Composer 1.6.5 (latest)
- I'm not behind a proxy & no firewall
- Windows 10

**What Works :**

- composer self-update

**What does not work :**

- Installing a package
- I cannot reach https://packagist.org/ with firefox 61.0.1 (64bits) (unsecure connection : **MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT**)

The error i get with composer require :

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

**php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());" Returns this :**

```
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(25) "c:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(22) "c:/usr/local/ssl/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(24) "c:/usr/local/ssl/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(16) "c:/usr/local/ssl"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(51) "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.9/extras/ssl/ca-bundle.crt"
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**I've downloaded the ca-bundle.crt and added it to my php.ini file :**

```
curl.cainfo=C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.9/extras/ssl/ca-bundle.crt    
openssl.cafile=C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.9/extras/ssl/ca-bundle.crt
```

**Composer diagnose returns this :**

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.6.5
PHP version: 7.1.9
PHP binary path: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.exe
```

**composer show -p -vvv | grep ssl returns this :**

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\extras\ssl\ca-bundle.crt: valid
Executing command (C:\wamp64\www\projectName): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/********/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading C:\wamp64\www\projectName/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin PackageVersions\Installer
Loading plugin Symfony\Flex\Flex
Composer >=1.7 not found, downloads will happen in sequence
Running 1.6.5 (2018-05-04 11:44:59) with PHP 7.1.9 on Windows NT / 10.0
ext-openssl         7.1.9    The openssl PHP extension
lib-openssl         1.0.2.11 OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

**php --ini :**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

**EDIT 1**
- Tried emptying cache
- Other web browser (chrome, edge) and it didnt work
- Another computer on same network --> it works

**EDIT 2**
- Created a new windows user, didnt work

**EDIT 3**
- I can reach **https://repo.packagist.org/** as suggested by **@kallosz**
- Curl gives me this :

```
curl -vvv https://packagist.org/
*   Trying 144.217.203.53...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to packagist.org (144.217.203.53) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with packagist.org port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 178 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 178 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with packagist.org port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with packagist.org port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1462
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1462 length 4096
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - La chaîne de certificats a été fournie par une autorité qui n'est pas approuvée.
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with packagist.org port 443
* schannel: clear security context handle
curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325)
```

Comment: I am able to access https://packagist.org/ without any errors...

Comment: @BogdanBurim, i get this error with firefox : MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

Comment: try to change `https://packagist.org` to `https://repo.packagist.org`

Comment: @kallosz I can reach https://repo.packagist.org with firefox. What should i do to make composer work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
composer config disable-tls true
composer config secure-http false
```

you can also change composer config `repositories.packagist.org.url` to `https?://repo.packagist.org`.

Comment: I won't run your 2 first cmds for security reasons. I added "repositories": {
        "packagist.org": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.packagist.org"
        }
    }   to my composer.json file, and now it works, but it means ill have to add it to all my projects that use composer. is there a way to set that globally ?

Comment: yes, you can add it to composer config. `composer config --editor --global`

Comment: ahhhh well i appreciate your help, at least you gave me a fallback solution. But id really like to solve my problem and make that default behaviour with packagist.org work, i just dont understand whats going on.

Comment: they change the address of the repository to a new one https://twitter.com/seldaek/status/1021740439475347456

Comment: after you update your repository check if your packagist URL is now correct.
`composer config --global --list` and `repositories.packagist.org.url` should look like this `[repositories.packagist.org.url] https?://repo.packagist.org`

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the global config file

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Composer\config.json

to this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "disable-tls": true,
        "secure-http": false
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://repo.packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall CURL development libraries on Ubuntu, i.e. replace NSS flavor to OpenSSL one:

```
sudo apt install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

The rebuilding PHP with [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew) resulted in libcurl enabled with appropriate library call; which, in turn, recognized CA certificates bundle correctly, pointing it to the *right location*.