# curl error 60 - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, curl, xampp, composer-php

I've installed Xampp 7.4.14 and composer on my local W10 machine.

When I run this command : composer diagnose, I get the following error:

Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have only one php.ini file, there's no other file in apache directory.

I've tried many values in php.ini for the following properties :

```
curl.cainfo="C:/xampp/apache/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
openssl.cafile="C:/xampp/apache/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
openssl.capath="C:/xampp/apache/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

I've tried to put cacert.pem and curl-ca-bundle.crt in different directories : C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl, C:\xampp\php, C:\xampp, C:\Windows, C:\Windows\System32, I've tried to write the path with '\' and '/'

I've tried to set some environment variables before running the "composer diagnose" command, nothing worked...
I always get this damn "curl error 60"...

Comment: [Does this question help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51553826/5897602)