# Composer install & Composer update not working - curl error 28 & curl error 60

Tags: curl, composer-php, homestead

Since yesterday I am having the issue that I cannot use `composer install` or `composer update` anymore, nor can I install a new version of Laravel. This all happened "suddenly", no changes were made on my part, not anywhere.

When changing nothing, network-wise, I get this error, the 60:

[image: curl error 60]

But when using a VPN or using my mobile phone as hotspot as a workaround, I get the 28 error:

[image: curl error 28]

I have also tried on my work computer, on my own home network, and it works fine there.

I have tried every solution from similar questions, too many to put down here. I have also re-installed Windows 10 and later Windows 11, and thus also re-installed Vagrant, VirtualBox, Homestead, and so on.

Tried disabling ipv6 entirely, tried using a different DNS, but the issue remains the same each time.

Also I have tried using Xammp instead of Homesteam, and also my regular cmd prompt instead of Git Bash. All to no avail.

At this point I am not sure what to do anymore. I thought about resetting my modem and router back to factory settings but if even the same issues occur using my mobile 4G connection, this will not solve anything.

If anyone has any ideas as to what might cause this, it would be very helpful.

PS. A few of the solutions I have tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34883260/2257418
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67262129/2257418
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406806/2257418
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72082707/2257418
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67200453/2257418
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595064/2257418

Getting this error when browsing to `https://codeload.github.com`:

[image: Firefox cert error]

The certificate:

[image: Github Codeload Certificate]

This issue does not appear when using a VPN. Trying to figure out what is exactly wrong and how to solve it now, but just editing it here in case someone knows what is wrong / has a fix.

When trying to pull in my repo, I sometimes get this "error" as well:

[image: Github connection error]

Also have installed Windows 11 from scratch, same issue. Lastly I tried this fix, but same issue:

https://mattferderer.com/fix-git-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-windows

Composer diagnose results:

[image: Composer diagnose]

Edit: Also just tried on my girlfriend's computer and got the same errors. Only installed Xammp there and composer and tried to install laravel, nothing more.

Latest edit: I tried installing Ubuntu on a virtual machine and install laravel using composer. Same issue, with the certificate:

[image: Ubuntu error]

I tried browsing to `https://codeload.github.com` and got the same error. But here I had the option to `accept the risk and continue`. But then I got a warning from my hosting provider (I live in Barcelona so it's in Spanish):

[image: Vodafone error]

Translation:

[image: Translation]

So it could be all of this is being blocked by some firewall from my hosting provider. But then that would not explain 3 things:

1. I get the same issues when using my phone's 4G (but same provider so could make sense)
2. I can browse to `https://codeload.github.com` on my desktop now and it works (in a private window of Firefox same issue though)
3. On my work laptop I have no issues using composer or browsing to the `codeload` page.

Comment: Do you use any proxy server?

Comment: Nope, not at all, also disabled that just in case, but same issues :(

Comment: Did you check why the browser also complains about a self-signed certificate?

Comment: I have been looking into but not able to find out anything so far no but I will definitely look into it some more

Comment: What does "View certificate" yield?

Comment: Figured it out in the end, finally, no thanks to Vodafone lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems this Vodafone "Secure Net" was the issue. I disabled it in `My Vodafone` and immediately I could install a fresh copy of Laravel. I figured it out in the end by installing Ubuntu on my virtual box because there I had the option to `take the risk and continue` to figure out it was the `Secure Net` blocking the access.

Now, after testing a bit more, and troubleshooting for 3 days, everything is working again like a charm!